# CSS 3D Transform property

Tags: html, css, transform, fallback

I am creating a 'Flip' effect using the CSS3 transform Property.

I have something that is working well in recent versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari but I'm afraid I'm finding hard to build some sort of fallback for IE9 and Opera as they only support 2d transforms.

I have created a fiddle to show what code I'm currently working with.

Please find the link to this here: http://jsfiddle.net/montyhog/SaYUe/9/

I'm not necessarily trying to recreate the effect in these browsers just create a fallback where when IMG1 is hovered IMG2 fades in etc on top.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="h1older">
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
<div class="flipper">
<div class="front"><img src="http://www.hogshouse.com/fbtest/img/cdartwork/meds.png" /></div>
<div class="back"><img src="http://www.hogshouse.com/fbtest/img/cdartwork/back.png" /></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.h1older {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px #ff00d5 dashed;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container:OnClickListener .flipper, .flip-container.OnClickListener .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container:focus .flipper, .flip-container.focus .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #139eef;
}

.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.front img {
    width: 100%;
}

.back img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-o-tramsform:
```

and

```
-ms-transform:
```

Transitions should work for IE and Opera. Make another 2 alt rows for every transition you make.